# Waiting data while dynamically loading templates in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In my meteor.js application, I am dynamically loading the templates;

```
  {{#DynamicTemplate template=getTemplate data=getData}}
    Default content when there is no template.
  {{/DynamicTemplate}}
```

When I am loading sub-templates, is it possible to wait to render the sub-template until sub-templates's data ready which comes from getData? I mean is there something like waitOn function  of the iron-router that I can do? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach you could take is to subscribe in the template's `created` function, then when rendering the template, first check each subscription's `ready()` and if they aren't all true, then render a loading display.

```html
<template name="templateWithSubscription">
  {{#if ready}}
    <!-- actual content -->
  {{else}}
    loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.templateWithSubscription.created = function () {
  this.subscriptions = [
    Meteor.subscribe(/* ... */),
    Meteor.subscribe(/* ... */),
    /* ... */
  ];
};

Template.templateWithSubscription.destroyed = function () {
  _.each(this.subscriptions, function (sub) {
    sub.stop();
  });
};

Template.templateWithSubscription.helpers({
  ready: function () {
    return _.all(Template.instance().subscriptions, function (sub) {
      return sub.ready();
    });
  }
});
```

A similar approach can be used for other data sources (e.g. methods).

Comment: How can I do multiple subscriptions and stop them on destroy?

Comment: This article is super-helpful too, especially if you want to add a dynamic data-context that updates based on something (e.g. pagination). https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` in templates

or

`Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()` in js code. And of course you can use `this` keyword as the reference to the current template.